# how to access GSA API

Tags: http, curl, cygwin, google-search-appliance

I have a Google Search Appliance and am trying to access the API to download the Event Logs.  I am using curl through cygwin on the Windows 7 command line.

I am able to get an authentication token using

```
curl -X POST -d Email=username -d Passwd=password "http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8443/accounts/ClientLogin"
```

My problem is that when I attempt to retrieve the even logs themselves:

```
curl -k -X GET -d query=User -H "Content-type: application/atom+xml" -H "Authorization: GoogleLogin Auth=e73265ce254f7c4afbcbee1743a56e81" "http://10.29.5.5:8000/feeds/logs/eventLog"
```

curl says that it cannot reach the host:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Any help in getting this to work is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the configuration with my GSA.  The GSA is configured to require communication over HTTPS.  Because all GSAs default to HTTP traffic over port 8000 and HTTPS traffic over 8443, my problem was solved by sending the following:

```
curl -k -X GET -d query=User -H "Content-type: application/atom+xml" -H "Authorization: GoogleLogin Auth=e73265ce254f7c4afbcbee1743a56e81" "https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8443/feeds/logs/eventLog"
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am trying to access the GSA in java using the following code                                        import com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaClient;
GsaClient myClient = new GsaClient("gsaAddr", gsaPort, "myUserId", "myPassword");                                                        My question is how can I add the authentication token in java ? any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can telnet to the IP-address. If you get a timeout there you should check firewalls etc.

```
C:\> telnet 10.29.5.5 8000
```

This looks like a more generic network problem than a problem with either the GSA or Curl.

Comment: You may be right. I cannot telnet to port 8000. However I can telnet to port 8443 at the same address. This I guess would imply that the machine is not listening on that port. Any idea how to fix this?